# Electrum shows "No FX rate available" and balances show "No Data" and last transaction doesn't appear

Tags: electrum, exchange-rate, balance

My Electrum 2.8.2 shows "No FX rate available" at the bottom and shows "No Data" for the balances. Also, I'm missing a transaction that someone said they sent to me. How do I fix this to see my latest transactions and USD balances?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your Electrum client isn't connected to an Electrum server?

Comment: It says it is. There is text in the 'Console' tab and the green light is on in the corner.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a bit more information what you've tried.— I assume that you've tried to "turn it off and on" again? ;)

Comment: Try connecting to a different Electrum server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just had this problem as well. It looks like Electrum gets its currency information by default from the BitcoinAverage website. You could try to select a different source of information. Try and see if this helps:

Go to Tools > Preferences > Fiat > Source > Select something like BlockchainInfo

Comment: This is a partial answer and could be improved by addressing the missing transaction reported by the asker.

Comment: Turns out the sender sent to the wrong address, an old address from an old wallet, but luckily I still had the key. Cost me a few bucks to sweep it though.